# Splitting strings in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, string, split

I have this code:

```
Dim StringParts As New List(Of String)(OriginalString.Split(New Char() {"\"c}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
```

When run, StringParts always have one element, because `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries = 1`.

How can I tell VB.Net to use the right function, and not understand `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` as a `count` parameter?

Thanks!

**Note:** Using `New String() {"\"}` instead of `New Char() {"\"c}` works. Is this a `.Net` bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unable to reproduce:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic

Public Class Test

    Public Shared Sub Main()
      Dim originalString As String = "a\b\c"
      Dim stringParts As New List(Of String)( _
          OriginalString.Split(New Char() {"\"c}, _
          StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
      Console.WriteLine(stringParts.Count)
    End Sub    

End Class
```

The above code prints 3 (compiled with both VS2010 and VS2008, to avoid this being a missing overload issue). In both cases the compiled code *is* using the enum value appropriately, rather than converting it into a number.

I suspect your problem lies elsewhere. Please try to edit your question with a short but complete program which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Indeed, I must have done something wrong at some point. Sorry!

Answer (score 2):

I don't see where the problem is:

```
Dim OriginalString = "part1\part2\part3"
Dim StringParts As New List(Of String)( _
    OriginalString.Split( _
        New Char() {"\"}, _
    StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries _
    ) _
)
```

works as expected. `StringParts` contains 3 elements.